# Flutter - iOS Build Failing

Tags: flutter

[image]
[image]

Unable to install /Users/nuaiman/Desktop/Flutter/flutterfire_wallpaper_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on 99534617-E21D-4E49-A2FB-29C31ACE38A9. This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.
Command: xcrun simctl install 99534617-E21D-4E49-A2FB-29C31ACE38A9 /Users/nuaiman/Desktop/Flutter/flutterfire_wallpaper_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           912.5s
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Describe your problem better with providing Info.plist file code

Comment: I have added everything.. I still have the same issue

Comment: Hi, found any solution?

Comment: Any luck with this?? getting same issue after updating Xcode to 14

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the ios folder in your Flutter project then run in terminal:

```
flutter create .
```

This will regenerate the iOS project files, then run.

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced same problem.
In my case version and build numbers were not recognized at all.
[image]

Resolved by setting proper xcconfigs
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is “The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion. Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion. ”

[image]

You need to paste the following code in the list file：

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

Comment: try to solve this is by Creating the new flutter project and then copy the files that matters in the project from the existing project. @NuaimanAshiq

Answer (score 0):

just add the row "Bundle Version String (short)" on your info.plist (by the menu 'add new row')...
Let us know!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).